# How do we externalize an element of a model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\mathbf{Z} =(V^\mathbf{Z},\in^\mathbf{Z})$ denote a model of ZFC (not necessarily well-founded; but, its a set).

**Question 0.** If $\mathbf{G} \in V^\mathbf{Z}$ has the property that "$\mathbf{Z} \models \mathbf{G}\; \mbox{is a group},$" how do we obtain an *actual* group from $
\mathbf{G}$? More generally, how do we externalize an element of a model of ZFC?

**Question 1.** I get the feeling that we can only externalize $\mathbf{G} \in V^\mathbf{Z}$ if, letting $D \subseteq V^\mathbf{Z}$ denote the transitive closure of $\mathbf{G}$ with respect to $\in^\mathbf{Z},$ we have that $(D,\in^\mathbf{Z} \restriction D)$ is a well-founded structure (in the ambient universe). Is this feeling correct? If so, would it be fair to say that the significance of well-founded models of ZFC is that they're precisely those models whose every element is externalizable?

Comment: The externalisation is the same as in category theory: you take the set $\{ g \in V^\mathbf{Z} : g \in^\mathbf{Z} G \}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin, that just lifts the underlying set!

Comment: It's good enough to extract groups.

Comment: With regard to question 1. "the downward closure of $G$ with respect to $\in^Z$ is a well-founded subset of of $V^Z$ with respect to $\in^Z$". This is alway true since you assumed that $(V^Z, \in^Z) \models ZFC$, in particular the axiom of foundation.

Comment: @William, I see that I have not spoken clearly. The idea is to take the downward closure of $G$ with respect to $\in^\mathbf{Z}$, call the result $D$, and then to ask whether or not $(D,\in^\mathbf{Z} \restriction D)$ is well-founded (as opposed to whether or not $\mathbf{Z}$ believes that $(D,\in^\mathbf{Z} \restriction D)$ is well-founded).

Comment: @user18921 In original $V$, this is not neccessarily well-founded. I am not sure what you mean by "downward closure" (transitive closure), but $(G, \in^Z)$ is may not even be well-founded on the outside. I not sure if this will help you externalize the group. On the outside, $G \neq \{x \in Z : x \ E G\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The group (or at least isomorprphic copy) is already a group on the outside. To elaborate.

So let say that $(V, \in)$ is your base universe of set theory. Let $(Z, E)$ be a $\{\in\}$-structure such that $(Z, E) \in V$, i.e. $(Z, E)$ is a set in $V$.

So by the assumption there is some $G \in^V Z$ such that $(Z,E) \models G$ is a group. More precisely there is a set $\cdot \in^V Z$ such that $(Z,E) \models (G, \cdot)$ is a group.

As $G, \cdot \in V$, you may want to guess that $V \models (G, \cdot)$ is a group already. However this is not true since there is no reason $\cdot$ is a binary relation on $G$ (as $\in$ and $E$ may not agree since $E$ may not equal $\in$).

Therefore let $\tilde G = \{x \in Z : x \ E \ G\}$ which exists by comprehension in $V$. Let $\times = \{(a,b) \in Z : (a,b) \ E \ \cdot\}$.

Now to just check that $V \models (\tilde G, \times)$ is a group. I will just check that there is an identity. Since $(Z,E) \models (G, \cdot)$ is a group. $(Z,E)$ proves that there is some $e \ E \ G$ such that for all $a \ E \ G$, $a \cdot e = e \cdot a$. By how $\tilde G$ is defined, $e \in G$. By how $\times$ is defined, $e \times a = a \times e$. So $e$ is the identity in $(\tilde G, \times)$ as viewed in $V$. The other axiom should be similar.